# FFMPEG support for WebVTT subtitle inline cues

Tags: ffmpeg, webvtt

I am trying to "soft" embed webvtt subtitles into my video using FFMPEG. I need to be able to place to the subtitles at a specific location within the video as well.

I have created a webvtt file that goes along with my video however; when I pass this through FFMPEG and then try to play the video in VLC media player, the positioning seems to be ignored.

When I play the original video in VLC and then load the same webvtt subtitles file, the positioning is correct?

Does FFMPEG support the webvtt cues? It is very possible that I am not passing the correct flags to FFMPEG.

VTT EXAMPLE FILE (i.e. subtitle.vtt):

```
WEBVTT

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:03.000 line:-1 align:right
TESTING 1

00:00:04.000 --> 00:00:08.000 line:-1 align:right
TESTING 2
```

FFMPEG CLI:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i subtitle.vtt -c copy -c:s mov_text vttout.mp4
```

Test Cases:

1. Playing MP4 video in VLC and manually loading the webvtt subtitles -> position is correct.
2. Passing MP4 video through FFMPEG to soft embed the subtitles in container and then playing in VLC -> subtitles are present but position is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but does the mp4 mov_text support positioning?

What if you just do (changing the container to mkv):

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i subtitle.vtt -c copy  vttout.mkv
```

Does that include the positioning info?